# Set uiCulture automatically based on browser accept language

Tags: asp.net-mvc, globalization

How I can set the culture of the ui automatically based on the users'browser?
All I found about this is `Globalize.culture("pt-BR");` But it sets `pt-BR` as default and I dont want set this by default! I want only set this if the user is pt-BR!
How can I do this? And the validator methods, how can I set them for a specific culture?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In a ASP.NET MVC the `web.config` is the right place. There is a quick summary,  the first snippet shows, how could be e.g. `pt-BR` culture forced

```
<globalization 
    enableClientBasedCulture="false" 
    uiCulture="pt-BR" 
    culture="pt-BR" />
```

If application is ready to accept the culture from the client (browser), settings should be

```
<globalization 
    enableClientBasedCulture="true" 
    uiCulture="auto" 
    culture="auto" />
```

The above setting will take a *Language* selected in client browser (e.g. `cs-CZ` in my case). If none is defined then system settings will be used.
Final snippet shows, how to allow client to set and send intended culture, but in case that no *Language* is pre-selected, override the system setting with some other default value **pt-BR**

```
<globalization 
    enableClientBasedCulture="true" 
    uiCulture="auto:pt-BR" 
    culture="auto:pt-BR" />
```

**Extended**: culture settings for `jQuery` `validator` and numeric input

*Note: I am definitely not an expert in `jQuery` and globalization techniques. This is example how I do adjust `validator` to correctly process any numeric input*

razor View part *(`X()` is a shortcut for `new HtmlString()`)*:

```
var defaultThousandSeprator = "@X(culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator)";
var defaultDecimalSeprator = "@X(culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator)";
```

jQuery part (custom methods for min and max)

```
$.validator.addMethod("min", function (value, element, param)
{
  var num = value.replace(RegExp(" ", "g"), "") // remove spaces
          .replace(RegExp('\\' + defaultThousandSeprator, "g"), "") // thousand separator
          .replace(RegExp("\\" + defaultDecimalSeprator, "g"), "."); // fix decimals
  return this.optional(element) || num >= param;
});
$.validator.addMethod("max", function (value, element, param)
{
  var num = value.replace(RegExp(" ", "g"), "") // remove spaces
          .replace(RegExp('\\' + defaultThousandSeprator, "g"), "") // thousands
          .replace(RegExp("\\" + defaultDecimalSeprator, "g"), "."); // decimals
  return this.optional(element) || num <= param;
});
```

And then jQuery.validator evaluates input values for *cs-CZ*: `10 000,00` correctly as well as *en-US*: `10,000.00`.

Comment: But changing this doest'n influence in jquery validators(the validations keeps the same), so I need to change the culture with Globalize.js.

Comment: Ok, I do not know Globalize.js. To handle JS stuff, I use dynamically generated JS variables e.g.: `var defaultCulture = "@( CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name)"`; and then extending JS components like `$.datepicker.regional[defaultCulture || ''];`. But my answer was explaining how to allow client culture to be used, as you asked... There could be default, but overriden with client if provided

Comment: Yeah, thank. But I need to know how to work with globalize and the validations too.

Comment: I extended my answer, with some basic how to. This is the way, how C# part can render strings representing numbers based on CurrentCulture, while jQuery.validator still evaluate them... just a clue

Answer (score 1):

You need to write out the script from the web page (or master page):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Globalize.culture("<% = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ToString() %>");
</script>
```

That's it. Mind you, that I used `CurrentCulture` instead of `CurrentUICulture`, as this is what you should be using for formatting. If you need the translations (which I wouldn't do this way as it would hurt localizability), you'll need your original `CurrentUICulture`.