# How to set culture automatically based on browser accept language?

Tags: c#, web-config, globalization, culture

I tried to configure out `enableClientBasedCulture` key in `globalization` section of `web.config`. I've found the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13550990/1679310).

MSDN told they are not already supporting this option. Is there any replacement or analogue to implement this setting?

I don't want to write my own `DelegatingHandler` (to parse request header by hands) for this basic feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `<globalization uiCulture="auto" culture="auto" />` (without `enableClientBasedCulture`) in `web.config`  worked for me in ASP.NET MVC4.